# Allow the comment author to delete their own comments

Tags: comments, users, front-end, customization

I've looked high and low and I can't find anything that will allow the logged in comment author to delete their own comment from the front end. All I want is a delete link under their comment that will delete the comment and all it's meta.

Comment: Have you looked into [wp_delete_comment()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_comment)?

Comment: This is the plugin you need http://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-comment-editing/

Comment: Otherwise to do it manually you'll need to add the remove link to your comments template and then setup an action hook in your functions.php or similar to handle deleting the comment.

Comment: Thanks Tim, any help to show me how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What file would I need to edit in the above plugin to make the ability to delete the comment without any expiration time?